# create stdclass with several arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop, stdclass

I'm trying to create new stdclass with several arrays inside, and then to convert it to json array, for example i have this arrays:

```
$my_arr = array (name=>myname1, adress=>myadd1, phone=>myphone1);
$my_arr2 = array (name=>myname2, adress=>myadd2, phone=>myphone2);
```

**And i would like to merge them to STDClass, This is what i have try:**

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->item1 = array();

foreach ($my_arr as $key => $value) {
$foo->item1[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($foo);
echo json_encode($foo);
```

The problem here is that i'm using only with the first array, **The Result should be:**

```
"items":[
    [
        {
            "name":"myname1",
            "adress":"myadd1",
            "phone":"myphone1"
        },
        {
            "name":"myname2",
            "adress":"myadd2",
            "phone":"myphone2"
        },
        {
            "name":"myname3",
            "adress":"myadd3",
            "phone":"myphone3"
        }
    ]
],
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: **array_merge**? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: your code have too much typo

Comment: I know, i wrote it fast.. i just wanted you will understand the main idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `stdClass`, just array will work well.

```
$foo = array('items' => array($my_arr, $my_arr2));
echo json_encode($foo);
```

Of course you could use `stdClass` also:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->items = array($my_arr, $my_arr2);
echo json_encode($foo);
```